# Sort by amount of bits set in bitmask

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, select, binary

I have a field in my table which represent bitmask. I'd like to sort the table by the amount of bits set, descending.

For example, bitmask `8` in binary is `1000`, i.e. only one bit set here, and bitmask `10` is `1010` it has two bits set, so it should be higher that `8`.

Another example: `16` is `10000` in binary, so it should be lower, than `1010` (10), which contains two ones.

An example below, here's a table unsorted

```
| bitmask |    bitmask binary for convenience
-----------
| 3       |    0000011   (2 bits set)
| 64      |    1000000   (1 bit set)
| 49      |    0110001   (3 bits set)
| 15      |    0001111   (4 bits set)
```

And what sorting I am trying to achieve:

```
| bitmask |    bitmask binary for convenience
-----------
| 15      |    0001111   (4 bits set)
| 49      |    0110001   (3 bits set)
| 3       |    0000011   (2 bits set)
| 64      |    1000000   (1 bit set)
```

In other words, an entry should be higher, if it has more bits set in binary representation.

I realize that I should probably take each number, get its binary representation, and check what bits are set.

Then *somehow sort by this value*.

But, I am completely unsure how to achieve this with MySQL only.

Could anyone give a hint or solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `bin` function to return the binary representation of the bitmask. From there, a neat dirty trick you could use to get the bitmask's popcount is to replace the zeros with empty strings and then check the length of the result:

```sql
SELECT   bitmask
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY LENGTH(REPLACE(BIN(bitmask), '0', ''))
```

Comment: Wow, that's a perfect solution! Thank you so much, really cool trick, would never thought of replacing zeros to sort by length

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY BIT_COUNT(bitmask)
```

Works if `bitmask` is a `BIGINT` (or smaller) or `BINARY`.  With version 8.0, it works in `BLOBs`, too.

```
SELECT BIN(1234), BIT_COUNT(1234);
+-------------+-----------------+
| BIN(1234)   | BIT_COUNT(1234) |
+-------------+-----------------+
| 10011010010 |               5 |
+-------------+-----------------+
```